# How to manage different menues in a multi-tenancy application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multi-tenant

i am developing a multi-tenancy application using java 17 and spring 2.6.3 for the backend and vue.js for the frontend. We have three tenants. These tenants all have different menus for the user. I have now a MenuService there i create the menues with if statement.
Like:

```
if (tenant.a) {
 getMenueEntry(enum.home, enum.setting, enum.support);
} else if (tenant.b) {
 getMenueEntry(enum.home, enum.setting, enum.support, enum.notification, enum.jobs);
} else if (tenant.c) {
 getMenueEntry(enum.home, enum.setting, enum.support, enum.jobs, enum.music);
}
```

is there a better way to handle this? Because there will be more tenants in the future and that means more if statements. Can i handle this with a property file? or to load the menue from the db?

Comment: Use security. Add an authority to each functional part of your application and dynamically build the menu based on that.

Comment: Is `getMenueEntry(tenant);` an option ? Meaning add the required information to tenant or tenant model.

Comment: @M.Deinum and how does my tenant know if it has a authorization to each menu. Where can I store this authorization?

Comment: @c0der then i must store the required information in the database or?

Comment: Database, files, mongo whatever you choose as your storage. Using Spring Security for this (I do assume and hope you have security on your mind) makes it relative easy to do.

Comment: Will you release a new version of your software for each new tenant? Or will he same version of software continue running as you add tenants? Your question is not clear about your requirements.

Comment: _i must store the required information in the database_ you need to [persist](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/6031811-persist-your-java-applications-data-with-the-repository-pattern) the information

Comment: @BasilBorque they have all the same version. Only some Tenants has other Functions. But the Core functions are the same